# Increase the RAM of a docker container itself (NOT DOCKER)

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-desktop

Hey guys I am running WSL 2 with a docker container running on the WSL2 but the docker container itself (its a KVM running QEMU VM) is limited to 4 GB I need a lot more than 4GB I need alt east 8 GB to run the things I want to run in QEMU VM (Theres a reason why I am running QEMU and no I cannot go without it)

I am running docker desktop and if I inspect the docker container it says the following

[image]

I have edited the .wslconfig file. and set the limit to 20GB as well as set the swap file to `1` and I have tried a command with docker run `insert_docker_name_here` it --memory 8000 -m
that then says it cant find the docker container for some reason but its under docker desktop.

I have tried looking on the internet for an answer but everything seems to point to .wslconfig file, --memory, or some vague answer that doesnt help at all, is there a way I can edit my docker container file and set it to use 8GB or more??

Please help - I am new to docker and would appreciate the asssistance

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory limit on docker containers by default. Using `--memory` will only specify the upper limit of memory the container can use. You need to examine how the docker container is started and remove any limit there.

Also the WSL2 has no memory limit by default and will just grab as much memory as it needs. The value in `.wslconfig` is also the upper limit. If you just remove all the limits, it should just use all available memory.

This leaves QEMU itself. Have you checked what the guest RAM size is? (`-m` parameter on the commandline)

Comment: no I have not - how can I check the guest RAM size ?

Comment: You should be able to check the running processes with something like `ps aux` in the WSL2. There you can see, if QEMU was started with the `-m` parameter.